# Rails: why insert with accepts_nested_attributes_for have a empty row?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, insert

I have a problem with rails when i insert to db: alway have a row if i set doc_items_attributes is [] a there is a row empty with foreign key and id

```
class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible  :doc_items_attributes, :partner_info

  has_many :doc_items, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :doc_items, allow_destroy:true
```

model doc_items

```
class DocItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :qty, :doc_id
  belongs_to :doc
```

data:

```
  params = { :doc => {
  :partner_info => 'john', :doc_items_attributes => [
    { :qty => '1' },
    { :qty => '2' }
   ]
  }}



doc = Doc.new()

doc.assign_attributes(params)    

doc.doc_items.build

doc.save
doc.doc_items.length #3
```

There is a empty row without data in table doc_items, but doc_id have value.

doc:

```
id partner
1 john
```

doc_items:

```
id doc_id qty
1   1     1
2   1     2
3   1
```

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 1):

You are building a new empty doc item in the

> doc.doc_items.build

line. That is the empty row.

You might want use the build method to build the doc_items.

```
doc = Doc.create( :partner_info => "john")
doc.doc_items.build(:qty => '1')
doc.doc_items.build(:qty => '2')    
doc.save
```

Comment: Hi Arnaldo, doc_items is a hash with many row and many column so i don't want to add by manual. i don't know why rails insert an empty row behind my data. it is not logical

Answer (score 0):

I found it

remove this line it works

```
doc.doc_items.build
```